# IPv6 forwarding seems to only work in one direction

Tags: routing, ipv6, ip-forwarding

**I now know the answer:** I did a bad mistake and did not even tell you. There was also a running `radvd` for router advertisment and instead of RA'ing a 64-net I was RA'ing a 56-net. So the router and/or the gateway always asked a `who has...` solicitation message, which means that it thought it is in the same subnet as the ping'ed server.

I am playing around with some IPv6 routing and addresses and facing a weird problem and can't figure out. I can only ping from one direction but not the other way around.

Let's say I have 3 PC's and a router:

```
Client[eth0] <---> [lan1]Router[wan] <---> [box0]Gateway[eth0] <---> [eth0]Server
```

*The Client, Gateway and Server are LXC Container and are working totally fine with IPv4!*

The Gateway is running a DHCPv6 server which delegates a prefix (`2001:db8:0:1::/56`) through interface `box0` so the router gets an IP-address (`2001:db8:0:1:8856:7cf8:8e46:d8cb`) and the client configures itself.

The interface `box0` on the gateway has a static IP from the same subnet: `2001:db8:0:1::1234:1`.

The interface `eth0` on the gateway has a static IP from another subnet: `2001:db8:0:2::4321:1`. See the changed `2` in the prefix.

The interface `eth0` of the server has a static IP from the same subnet as eth0@gateway has: `2001:db8:0:2::4321:2`

I first enabled IPv6 forwarding with

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Now I did set up a route on the gateway which leads into the /56 subnet

```
ip -6 route add 2001:db8:0:1::/56 via 2001:db8:0:1:8856:7cf8:8e46:d8cb
```

And a default route for the server

```
ip -6 route add default via 2001:db8:0:2::4321:1
```

---

**My Problem is:** I can ping everything from the server side (except the client because the router blocks it) but I'm unable to ping anything behind eth0@gateway from the router side.

Did you encounter this, for me, strange behaviour? Do you need further information, like routing table etc.?

Comment: The routing on the servers should be setup automatically.  IPv6 has a lot more auto-configuration than IPv4.  Try removing the route you manually added.

Comment: The DHCP server only runs on box0@gateway and not on eth0. So I need to set it up manually. I know I can run a second DHCP server but it is not necessary for me in this scenario. If I remove the route I have to use `ping6 -I eth0 ...` on the server to ping the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple and is traced back to missconfiguration.

There was also a running `radvd` for router advertisement and instead of RA'ing a 64-net I was RA'ing a 56-net. So the router and/or the gateway always asked a who has... solicitation message, which means that it thought it is in the same subnet as the ping'ed server.